How to diagnose why I can't access some URLs but not others from a Linux machine
I'm running openSUSE (Tumbleweed), which has worked fine for ages. After running sudo zypper DUP a few weeks ago (and since) suddenly there's a network issue with only some URLs.
The ones I can't access come back with 'Unable to connect'
Here are some examples...
Can access:

ibm.com
google.com
and some others

Can't access:

duckduckgo.com
sainsbury.com
gov.uk
stackoverflow.com
and most others

I don't run a firewall on this machine, as I rely on the one on the router (does that make me a bad person?)
I don't run a proxy
I recently upgraded my router from an old version of openwrt to the latest version (the problem's probably coincidental, rather than as a result but I thought I'd mention it, just in case! I can access sites fine from other machines, so I think it's unlikely to be the router.
I have tried accessing the these sites from Firefox Nightly and a recent Vivaldi (Chrome fork) and tried pinging the domains from a Konsole (no luck). Also Proton mail bridge tells me there's no network access, though there clearly is for some things.
NeetworkManager (NM) seems to be running OK - set up for static IP. DNS on my router is not set but for NM on the desktop mentioned, I have the following:
84.200.69.80, 84.200.70.40, 149.112.112.112 & 9.9.9.9
What should I be looking for? What am I missing?
I can supply current config on demand but don't want to start out spamming all of it.
I have tried pinging from a) a bash console and b) my router's diagnostics page
From bash, I successfully: ping ibm.com and get the times back but when I try ping duckduckgo.com or ping stackoverflow.com, I get Network is unreachable. Actual output now pasted below - gotta say, even the successful one looks kinda weird!
ping ibm.com
PING ibm.com (2a02:26f0:e8:191::3831) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-00e8-0191-0000-0000-0000-3831.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:e8:191::3831): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=4.34 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-00e8-0191-0000-0000-0000-3831.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:e8:191::3831): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=4.08 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-00e8-0191-0000-0000-0000-3831.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:e8:191::3831): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=3.91 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-00e8-0191-0000-0000-0000-3831.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:e8:191::3831): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=4.26 ms

ping stackoverflow.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

If I try the same pings from my router diagnostics page, they all work OK!?

Since this is some sites and not others, the first place to look is check DNS. There's various commands to see what's happening but perhapse smiplest is to use ping and ping6 on each domain name to see if they resolve to IPv4 and IPv6 addresses respectivly and if you can gett packets through to them. Id you are sure you don't have IPv6 (eg Virgin Media) then just check the V4 ones. Most of those websites should return pings.

I can't copy and paste the ACTUAL ping output because I do that on my Linux box (no access to this site) but I'm editing this on my Mac (has access), but I have added a summary - hope that meets your request? @PhilipCouling

OK. Managed to send output to my phone, with KDE connect and then pasted it into Slack to myself and picked it up on Mac.

Just tried ping -4 ibm.com and it says network unavailable. Could it be that I've misconfigured ip4 on this machine and that the only sites that work are ones that support ip6?

That was my first instinct. Although some of those you can’t connect to have IPv6 addresses. Either way, it does look like IPv4 isn’t configured correctly.
